# Read utm query string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I am trying to read url parameters like the following:

```
http://www.someoneswebsite.com/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twit&utm_campaign=randomtwitter
http://www.someoneswebsite.com/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twit&utm_campaign=randomtwitter1
```

On my page, I have a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenVal" value="old value" />
```

I want to access utm_campaign and check if it contains the string "randomtwitter". If it does, change the value of the hidden field.

Here's what I have come up with:

```
var query = window.location.search;

if( query.indexOf('utm_campaign=randomtwitter') !== -1 ) {
     $('#hiddenVal').val('new value');
}
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.href` instead to get the location link :

```
var query = window.location.href;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var query = $(location).attr('href');

if( query.indexOf('utm_campaign=randomtwitter') !== -1 ) {
     $('#hiddenVal').val('new value');
}
```